API to get information/meta-data about a package from Package managers such npm, nuget, maven etc
I am working on a project, wherein i would like to  get data about a package and its dependencies from various sources such as npm, nuget, maven etc.
Is there any way to do it. For example

In the nuget package manager, I am able to see the information about dependencies, project url etc. Is there any api endpoints to get this information about the package from various sources like nuget, maven, github etc.
